# Javascript redirect then show a message

Tags: javascript

I'm using a basic timed redirect to logout function and would like it to display a message in the location of my choosing after the redirect has completed,  IE on a different page to where the redirect was called.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">   
   function Redirect() 
   {  
   window.location="../../../../Applications/logout.asp"; 
   } 
   setTimeout('Redirect()', 5000);   
   </script>
```

I know I can use the basic alert or write, but I'd specifically like the message to be shown in a div of my choice on the target page, is that even possible?

Comment: Not unless you discover an XSS vulnerability. If the page you're redirecting to can receive `POST`/`GET` variables and display them properly, you can leverage those.

Comment: After you redirect, scripts on the old page stop running.

Comment: Can you not just change the page you are redirecting to?

Comment: just throw a hash or get param on the end of the redirect url, and use it so the new page knows.  or use a cookie.  or do lots of other possible things....

Comment: Thanks for the useful comments. @abl do you not have anything better to do with your life? Not sure why stackoverflow has become a place for buffoons to post useless comments, almost scolding people for coming here for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a parameter to the page you are redirecting, kind of like

```
window.location="../../../../Applications/logout.asp?sessionTimeOut=true";
```

and then check this parameter on the other page. If it is TRUE you can put a specific message on whenever you want.